# IBM Q - Individual Run Results

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

In Qiskit, is there a way to get the individual results from each shot on the IBM quantum device (instead of simply the summary statistics)? The result JSON file provides the count of all the 1024 shots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `memory=True` in `assemble()` or `execute()`. Then use `result.get_memory()` to get the per-shot measurement.

For example:

```
job = execute(circs, memory=True, shots=4)
result = job.result()
print(result.get_counts(0))  # prints {'00': 3, '11': 1}
print(result.get_memory(0))  # prints ['00', '00', '11', '00']
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this documentation will help you: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Result.html#qiskit.result.Result.get_memory

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
provider = IBMQ.load_account()

circuit = QuantumCircuit(3)

circuit.h(0)
circuit.h(1)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.cx(0, 2)
circuit.barrier(range(3))
circuit.h(0)
circuit.h(1)
circuit.barrier(range(3))
circuit.measure_all()
print(circuit)

job = execute(circuit, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots=10, memory=True)

print('result for each shot:', job.result().get_memory() )
```

```
     ┌───┐           ░ ┌───┐ ░ ┌─┐      
q_0: ┤ H ├──■────■───░─┤ H ├─░─┤M├──────
     ├───┤┌─┴─┐  │   ░ ├───┤ ░ └╥┘┌─┐   
q_1: ┤ H ├┤ X ├──┼───░─┤ H ├─░──╫─┤M├───
     └───┘└───┘┌─┴─┐ ░ └───┘ ░  ║ └╥┘┌─┐
q_2: ──────────┤ X ├─░───────░──╫──╫─┤M├
               └───┘ ░       ░  ║  ║ └╥┘
c: 3/═══════════════════════════╩══╩══╩═
                                0  1  2 
result for each shot: ['101', '001', '100', '100', '101', '101', '001', '100', '101', '100']
```